# How to convert Virtulabox VM to QEMU and preserve snapshots?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm-switch

Is there a way to convert my Virtualbox Virtual Machine (host Linux Mint 20 x64, guest machine Windows 10 x64) to a QEMU/KVM virtual machine and preserve the snapshots? Such that I do not have to full clone every snapshot to a qcow2 format which would take up a lot of disk space? AFAIK QEMU does support snapshots but I haven't found a way to convert the base VM disk image to qcow2 for QEMU *and* also export the snapshot files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely you could do this. Snapshots belong to the virtual machine and the Virtualizing App you use (I use VMware Workstation).

You need to combine and resolve snapshots first. Once done then you can convert to another Virtualizing App. The machine is not in a complete stable state until Snapshots have been resolved.

That is the normal way to do this.

If you are short of disk space, you can move the machine and snapshots (so whole machine folder) to a large USB drive. Leave it connected and resolve the snapshots that way.

Snapshots can be deleted once combined.

Comment: I have the space to fully resolve all snapshots to separate full clone but I don't wish to do so as it would be wasteful. If the snapshot scheme is somewhat proprietary to Virtualbox then I might resolve the base snapshot and manually rebuild my snapshots from there on. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are very welcome and Good Luck with your ultimate conversion. Once you do the combination of snapshots (if you do) the left over snapshots can be deleted.